# Azure DataFactory Retain LastModified Date when copying file

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to (automatically, but as part of a pipeline) archive some existing files, by moving them to a new folder.

I've written a pipeline to do that, but since it's a "Copy-and-delete-Original" command, the new file has a new Timestamp.

Is there any way to retain the original timestamps, either by *actually* moving the file, or by explicitly setting the LastModified date? (there doesn't appear to be a setting on the copy data activity to retain the Timestamp :(

Comment: Can you tell that I've just picked up ADF for the first time :) other beginner questions also recently posted under the same tag.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is supported through ADF's web UI.  I could be wrong, but I haven't see a way to do it.

But you could call the REST API for Blob services and set the lastmodifieddate that way.  You could get the file's original lastmodifieddate using the getmetadata activity and then copying the file to the new location, and then call the REST API and reset the property.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-properties